# GET Method in facebook graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

As far I have seen in Graph API, there is a seperate method to get_user,get_ID,get_email etc details. Is there any generic get or update or upsert or search method in Graph API r some other API to get the information from facebook profile?

Is there any documentation like other API's to see the methods available in GRAPH API?

What is the jar name in which GRAPH API exists to use in my java code?

Comment: The API documentation is at http://developers.facebook.com/docs - there's links there to the supported SDKs including Android

Comment: Thank you for reply. May I know the jar name for graph api?

Answer (score 0):

Too many questions in a single one.

1. Specific fields query: For this you should have a look at FQL. It returns specif result , much a sql query.
2. Documentation: Facebook has excellent documentation on graph and other useful  APIs have a look at developers.facebook.com.
3. Jar Name: I cannot name specific jar but you can find complete facebook client library on any language. Also available in Java.